# Align static blocks in footer

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, widgets, footer, widget-instance

Trying to line up static blocks in footer. See picture - want to have all 4 link columns across page. Magento 1.9 Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please share a link to the webshop in question. Without a link it's impossible to check what the issue is.

Comment: In all likelihood, the container of that footer needs to have its width set to 100%, but, like @MilanSimek said, we need to either see the source or the site.

Comment: Here's the site http://bulklolliesnz.co.nz/store/

Comment: Please share your footer code here.

Comment: Please check the answer by Qaisar Satti. That's correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the `clear:both` for `widget` class.

```
.widget {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not putted the code in correct div,Your block should be in this way :-

```
<div class="bottom-container">
<div class="widget widget-static-block">
<div class="links">
<!--your Customer Info block goes here -->
</div> 
</div>
<div class="widget widget-static-block">
<div class="links">
<!--your Company Info block goes here -->
</div>
 </div>
<div class="widget widget-static-block">
<div class="links">
<!--your Quick Links block goes here -->
</div>
 </div>
<div class="widget widget-static-block">
<div class="links">
<!--your Account block goes here -->
</div>
 </div>
</div>
```